# Can I change my location with OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have setup an OpenVPN client and when I want to activate the vpn I type `openvpn client.ovpn` in my terminal. So far so good.

Is there some way to make it seem like I am browsing from another country?
I have found some vpnmclients online,ready to do what I want, but they are only for buying. So is there a way to do it for free with OpenVPN or some other vpn client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are free VPN-Plans out there. A few providers allow free users to use their vpn services like (i didn't try them myself):

- ProtonVPN https://protonvpn.com/pricing
- FreeVPN https://freevpn.me/accounts/

also u might want to have a look at the list at
PrivacytoolsIO: https://www.privacytools.io/#vpn

When a vpn connection is established u might want to do a dns leaktest at https://dnsleaktest.com/

If you want to browse most anonymous as possible you should use the tor-browser bundle from the torproject website https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en